# Custom Row for List View

Tags: java, android, listview, material-design

I am trying to build this custom row for my ListView. Through the magic of Photoshop here is what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

But when I run my list view,  it is coming out like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong with the view?

**Here is my row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/COLOR_GREY" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Item Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Item Name"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <!-- progress count -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Item Name"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <!-- Retry button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRetry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/txtItemName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtItemName"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="Retry" />

    <!-- Delete button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/btnRetry"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnRetry"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="Delete" />

    <!-- ProgressBar -->
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtItemName"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/txtItemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarItem" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: First of all, `RelativeLayout` doesn't use "orientation", LinearLayout` does, then, when you are referencing a view you don't use the `+` sign  when accessing its ID, it is only used to create a new ID. So first I would fix this. And you are using the full width to the layout with the ImageView making the other elements to appear out of the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the layout mostly done as on your picture, just need to change with the buttons in order to make them looks better.

In RelativeLayout you do not need to use **orientation**
and for text use **sp** instead of **dip**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/row"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:baselineAligned="false"
     android:gravity="center_vertical">

<!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_image"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<!-- Item Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItemName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/list_image"
    android:text="Item Name"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<!-- progress count -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="100"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<!-- Retry button -->
<Button

    android:id="@+id/btnRetry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnDelete"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnDelete"
    android:text="Retry" />

<!-- Delete button -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:text="Delete" />

<!--&lt;!&ndash; ProgressBar &ndash;&gt;-->
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtItemName"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtProgress"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txtProgress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_image"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/list_image"
    android:progress="100"
    android:id="@+id/progressBarItem" />
```

You can find other tips how to work with layouts by doing small parts of the layout and searching them in the stackoverflow and then you can learn how to do bigger layouts. Because before you really needed to wrap some components into linear layouts, but now with Android Studio 2.2 you can use ConstraintLayout

Comment: Sorry, using your layout nothing appears now.

Comment: I have checked from design page, it works. How do you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Why you using ImageView inside LinelarLayout?

Check this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/COLOR_GREY" />

    <!-- Item Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtItemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/list_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_image"
        android:text="Item Name"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <!-- progress count -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/list_image"
        android:text="Item Name"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />


    <!-- Delete button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/btnRetry"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="Delete" />

    <!-- Retry button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRetry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/txtItemName"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="Retry" />

    <!-- ProgressBar -->
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/list_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txtProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBarItem" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, don't forget that textSize should be in **sp**

If you want to change button sizes - just replace:

> ```
>   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> ```

and put your custom width and height in dp like:

> ```
>   android:layout_width="25dp"
>   android:layout_height="25dp"
> ```

Comment: and keep in mind that you have to create a new layout for different screen-sizes since you chose to set a fixed width and height

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie Yep, Thanks!)

Comment: Sorry, using your layout nothing appears now.

Comment: did you properly closer Relative Layout Tag? </RelativeLayout>

Comment: could you please provide me with your full class? and ListView adapter please.